# Homebrew tap formula update

Tags: homebrew

So I have a few homebrew packages that I maintain. When I release a tagged version of one of the packages, I have a cumbersome dance that I have to do in order for the whole process to work end to end. It is as follows:

- Update package and tag with new version number

  - Push to github
- Update the `URL` in my homebrew formula to the new tag

  - Push formula to github
- brew upgrade [package]

  - when it gives me the `sha256` error I copy and paste the `Actual` sha256 into the formula file and push it again up to github.
- problem solved

Bellow is the error I get when I `brew upgrade [package]`

```
Error: SHA256 mismatch
Expected: f95ec88f22bd217271199695593f9a217cc0fc3b69469e31cafd09f0a55dc1a4
Actual: 3b52516206cdec8fd85f74c5d346665195fdef3095dc7665a680e48842edd5cf
```

I have tried to generate the `sha256` locally before I commit the formula to github and it never matches:

```
shasum -a 256 [package]
```

I have tried downloading the tarball and issuing the same command on the tar.gz and it doesnt match either.

```
curl -O http://address/0.0.9.tar.gz
shasum -a 256 0.0.9.tar.gz
```

What gives? I am sick of doing this dance. There has to be a less cumbersome way that only involves me committing my formula file once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### SOLVED

The problem was with the `curl` command.

The following command will output the correct `sha256` checksum to put in the formula file.

#### Using Curl

```
curl -Ls https://address/0.0.9.tar.gz | shasum -a 256
```

#### Using wget

```
wget -qO- https://address/0.0.9.tar.gz | shasum -a 256
```